# How this code works (Have as I input only a integer )?

Tags: c

I was trying to make a code that gets only an integer as input. I found a working solution [here](https://jackstromberg.com/2013/02/how-to-validate-numeric-integer-input-in-c/)

```
int n, input, temp, status;

printf("Height:");
status = scanf("%d",&n);

while(status!=1)
{
    while((temp=getchar()) != EOF && temp != '\n');
    printf("Height:");
    status = scanf("%d", &n);
}
```

I want to know what exactly makes this part work and what are those "extra hidden characters"

```
while((temp=getchar()) != EOF && temp != '\n');
```

Can anyone explain, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user enters some non-numeric input (for example `foo` instead of an integer) then [`scanf` will return](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value) `0` and *leave* the non-numeric input in the input buffer.

So the next time you call `scanf` it will attempt to read the exact same non-numeric input and fail again.

The loop

```
while((temp=getchar()) != EOF && temp != '\n');
```

will read character by character until either it comes to and end of file, or the character is a newline. The characters the loop reads will be ignored and thrown away.

This is a way to skip all the non-numeric input that the user might have entered.

Answer (score 3):

> while((temp=getchar()) != EOF && temp != '\n');

First, you need to understand what [getchar](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_getchar.htm) function does, namely:

> The C library function int getchar(void) gets a character (an unsigned
> char) from stdin.
>
> **Return Value**
> This function returns the character read as an unsigned char cast to an int or > EOF on end of file or error.

When the user types something that will be picked by the `scanf`, the user press an `[enter]` which will send a "\n". That newline will not be read by the `scanf` function but rather stay on the input buffer. The `EOF` is for the case that someone explicitly closes the stream, for instance pressing CTRL-Z. So the code:

```
 while(status!=1)
    {
        while((temp=getchar()) != EOF && temp != '\n');
        printf("Height:");
        status = scanf("%d", &n);
    }
```

check first the returning type value of the [scanf](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm) which:

> Return Value On success, **the function returns the number of items of
> the argument list successfully read**. If a reading error happens or the
> end-of-file is reached while reading, the proper indicator is set
> (feof or ferror) and, if either happens before any data could be
> successfully read, EOF is returned.

In your case, you expect to read a single numerical value (`i.e., status = scanf("%d",&n);`). The remains of the loop is basically asking for the user to provide a valid input (*i.e.*, a numeric value), which consequently leads to `status` being `1`, and the exit of the outermost while loop.

Answer (score 0):

The EOF character is received when there is no more input. The name makes more sense in the case where the input is being read from a real file, rather than user input (which is a special case of a file).
This means that your loop will break when you receive an EOF or if the user hits enter, in this case, you receive a '\n'.